# Creating a dev environment on an external ssd drive (Windows primarily)

Tags: windows, development-environment

I have an older Lenovo T480s with these specs:

- Processor: 8th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-8650U with vPro™ (1.90GHz, up to 4.20GHz with Turbo Boost, 8MB Cache)
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64
- Display Type: 14.0" FHD (1920 x 1080) IPS, anti-glare, touchscreen, 250 nits
- Memory: 16GB (8GB Soldered + 8GB DIMM) 2400MHz
- Hard Drive: 512GB SSD PCIe

I have been doing more development and testing work recently and I would like to put all of the dev tools (Python (anaconda), Node.js, npm, Visual Studio, VSC, git, etc.) on an external 1TB SSD drive to free up space on my C: drive.

My goals are:

- To free up space on the C drive for the other work I do
- To have a standalone drive that I can hook up to another PC and work with the same tools, with as little fuss as possible. If this is at all possible
- Optional: split the 1T drive in two and have a Linux partition on it to boot up and work on also

My questions: what is the best way to go about doing something like this? Where can I find a guide that covers the steps?

Thanks,

L

Comment: For Visual Studio, no-can-do (at least, this was true in every version up to and including 2017, so I doubt it changed).  The other tools you mentioned are more likely to have "portable installation" options.

Comment: To find such guides, pick one tool at a time, and use your favorite Internet search engine with a query of "(name-of-tool) portable install Windows".  First hit for VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable